# Yii2 Query based on Select2 selected Item

Tags: yii2, jquery-select2, yii2-advanced-app

Good Afternoon,

I am very new to Yii2 so this may be very simple.

I have built a select2 to return the related ID:

VIEW:

```
<?=  $form->field($model, 'part_id')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'name' => 'Partselect',
   'data' => $items,
   'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select a item ...', 'attribute' => 'category','id'=>'id_select'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
            'allowClear' => true
        ],
    'pluginEvents' => [
        "change" => 'function() {
            var part_id = $(this).val();
             //alert(part_id);
        }',
    ]

]); ?>
```

Controller:

```
 $modelp = PartsSearch::find()
        -> where(['ID'=> ('part_id')])
        -> all();
```

The two tables are relational

I want to display 'cost_price_nett' from the partssearch table based on what ever is selected in the drop down.

Any help would be perfect!

Comment: Hi maybe this [doc](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record#joining-with-relations) can help you.

Comment: I had read this but where im struggling is getting it refresh everytime the kartik/select2 is changed.

Comment: you have function on change event